# JS/jQuery Code - Scrolling up/down triggers event (Smooth scrolling to Div Classes)

Tags: javascript, jquery

For the front-end of one of the eCommerce sites I'm designing, I'd like to simulate an effect shown in the following: [Qards Theme](http://designmodo.com/qards/)

I think I understand how to setup smooth scrolling anchors, but I need someone to show me the code for triggering the event of smooth scrolling to div classes, **as a result of the user scrolling up/down.**

It would be helpful if someone could identify the name of the effect, shown in the Qards Theme, as there is likely online reference material. In fact, I'd like to hand-code an almost exact replica (hopefully more lightweight) of the Qards theme (with my own text, images), but I guess this is a good place to start.

Disclaimer: New to HTML, CSS, and JS, kindly leave //explanatory comments with any code.

Comment: Perhaps you could start with http://razorfish.github.io/Parallax-JS/#header

Comment: Thank you for this. It may just be me, but I can't seem to achieve the whole, smooth scrolling effect, from div to div, as a result of scrolling up/down, consistently. It seems to be a bit buggy. I'm somewhat familiar with the whole Parallax effect.